# ¿How set different background on pdfmake-wrapper's page?

Tags: angular, pdf, typescript-typings, wrapper, pdfmake

I am working with pdfmake-wrapper on Angular 13, but I don't understand how set a different background per page like this sample:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhu1w.png)

That is my method to generate my own pdf:

```
public async generateFormat() {
    let imageOne!: any;
    let imageTwo!: any;
    let ancho!: any;
    let alto!: any;
    if (this.licencia.format === 'Municipal') {
      imageOne = this.formatoObject.licFrenteMunicipio;
      imageTwo = this.formatoObject.licVueltaMunicipio;
      ancho = 85;
      alto = 54;
    } else {
      imageOne = this.formatoObject.licFrenteEstado;
      imageTwo = this.formatoObject.licVueltaEstado;
      ancho = 54;
      alto = 85;
    }
    const pdf = new PdfMakeWrapper();
    PdfMakeWrapper.setFonts(pdfFonts);
    pdf.add(await new Img(imageOne).width(ancho).height(alto).build().then(async img => {
      pdf.add(await new Img(this.licencia.photo).width(25).height(25).absolutePosition(25,25).build());
      pdf.background(img);
      pdf.pageSize({
        width: ancho,
        height: alto
      })
    }));
    pdf.add('\n');
    pdf.add(await new Img(imageTwo).width(ancho).height(alto).build().then(async img => {
      pdf.add(await new Img(this.licencia.firm).width(25).height(25).absolutePosition(25,25).build());
      pdf.background(img);
      pdf.pageSize({
        width: ancho,
        height: alto
      })
    }));
    pdf.create().open();
  }
```

And this is my result when I try it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XEfa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Pdfmake has a function called [background()](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/document-definition-object/background-layer/), which allows you to set a different background for each page :

```
var documentDefinition = {
    background: function(currentPage) {
        if (currentPage === 1) {
            return {img: 'SRC_TO_BACKGROUND1'}
        } else {
            return {img: 'SRC_TO_BACKGROUND2'}
        }
    },

    content: [
        {text: 'text', pageBreak: 'after'},  // will have background 1
        {text: 'text', pageBreak: 'after'},  // // will have background 2
    ]
};
```